# Remove Rows With Multiple Runs in R Dataframe Without Looping

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with a data frame that is measuring entries and exits. Sometimes, the criteria for an entry is met multiple times before an the exit critera happens, and vice versa. I would like to remove these instances. For example, in the data, there is an entry in row 1 and another in row 2, the one in row 2 needs to come out since we are already "In". Similarly, row 6 and 7 need to come out since we are already "out" and there has not been another entry. Also, it is worth mentioning that there cannot be an exit without a prior entry.

I know I can do this with a for loop but I would like to avoid that if possible. I have tried using cumsum to filter for a total sum of "In" + "Out" of 0 or 1, anything else has to go. That approach does not work.

Initial data frame:

```
   In Out
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   0  -1
4   1   0
5   0  -1
6   0  -1
7   0  -1
8   1   0
9   0  -1
10  0  -1
```

Desired Output:

```
   In Out
1   1   0
3   0  -1
4   1   0
5   0  -1
8   1   0
9   0  -1
```

Code to create initial data frame:

```
temp <- structure(list(In = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Out = c(0, 
0, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1)), .Names = c("In", "Out"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `rleid` from the "data.table" package?

Comment: `temp[sequence(rle(temp$In)$lengths) == 1, ]`

Comment: Rawr, thanks for the suggestion, if you make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(temp)[, ind:=rleid(Out)][,.SD[1L] , by = ind][, ind:=NULL][]
 #    In Out
 #1:  1   0
 #2:  0  -1
 #3:  1   0
 #4:  0  -1
 #5:  1   0
 #6:  0  -1
```

Or based on @Arun's comment

```
 setDT(temp)[, .SD[1L], by = list(ind=rleid(Out)), .SDcols=1:2][,ind:= NULL][]
```

Comment: or `setDT(temp)[, .SD[1L], by = rleid(Out), .SDcols=1:2]`

Comment: Akrun, thanks for this suggestion. I tried to use a data table before in this same exercise and R crashed.

Comment: @user2926358  I am using the devel version of data.table i.e. `data.table_1.9.5` on `R 3.2.1`.  Instructions to install it are [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution:

```
temp[c(TRUE,temp$In[-length(temp$In)]!=temp$In[-1]),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `data.table` solution. Do not need `v1.9.5`

```
setDT(temp)[c( TRUE , In[-.N] != In[-1] )]
```